# Use index in comparator function of sort()

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to sort an array and access the indeces of the elements I'm comparing in the comparator function.

For example, I hoped that something like this would work:

```
someArray.sort((a, b, indexOfA, indexOfA) => someFunction(indexOfA) - somFunction(indexOfB));
```

Comment: Pfff, if the values are all different, you could use `someArray.indexOf(a)` to find each index. But in that case, rolling your own sort function would be more efficient I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The only realistic way is to make a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) of the array to create `[index, element]` pairs before the sorting:

```
const transformed = someArray.map((element, index) => [index, element]);
```

You can now sort this based on the indices:

```
transformed.sort((a, b) => someFunction(a[0]) - someFunction(b[0]));
```

And then undecorate the array again:

```
someArray = transformed.map(i => i[1]);
```

You can probably integrate the `someFunction` call into the Schwartzian transform already so you don't have to call that function repeatedly for each item:

```
someArray = someArray.map((element, index) => [someFunction(index), element])
                     .sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])
                     .map(i => i[1]);
```

Answer (score -1):

`someArray.lastIndexOf(a)` could help

Comment: Only if the values are all different.

Comment: True, assuming the comparator works with non-primitives, otherwise, it's useless ...

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it